# Is it possible to avoid compile-time dependency using spring Java @Configuration?

Tags: java, spring, maven

Is there a way to declare beans using spring Java based configuration without compile-time checking, so that I can provide interface implementation at runtime?

For example, when I write a JAX-RS client, I use the JAX-RS API without referring to a specific API implementation. In my spring XML configuration, I then declare the actual implementation of the JAX-RS API that I want to use, e.g. Jersey, when setting up the client bean. Because XML based configuration is used (and verified) during runtime, I do not need compile time dependency to Jersey. This allows me to have a `<scope>runtime</scope>` Maven dependency to Jersey, while I must have a `<scope>compile</scope>` dependency to the JAX-RS API. The benefit of this approach is that if I accidentally use the implementation, my application won't compile with Maven.

On the other hand, if I use the Java based spring configuration (using `@Configuration`) to declare my beans, I must have a compile time dependency to the implementation of the API because the configuration itself is compiled.

If this is not possible to achieve with Java based configuration, are there any alternatives (besides using a combination of XML and Java based configuration which I know is possible)?

Comment: You could manually do the same thing via reflection, I suppose, but one of the advantages of strong typing is that ahead-of-time checking. Spring Boot autoconfiguration for implementation beans might be suitable for what you want.

Comment: Just mark the dependencies as `<optional>true</optional>`. For anything using your library it has still to manually declare the dependencies. This is basically the way Spring Boot is using things (marking a lot of things as optional and using conditional rules to include the desired java based configuration).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Short answer*:

Yes it's possible :)

*Long answer*:

Besides the described ways, Spring Boot provides this out of the box.

It's the way Spring Boot does it's autoconfiguration magic. A lot of options are only provided in the core Spring Boot Starter library only during compile time. But became active with the actual implementation when the necessary libraries (or to be precise classes) are available on the class path during runtime.

Spring Boot provides for this purpose specialized annotation: `@ConditionalOnClass`. 
I would recommend to read [this section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html) of Spring Boots documentation to get familiar with the topic.

Answer (score 1):

For your java configuration to compile, all the classes included in it have to be accessible at compile time.

You could move that @Configuration root class to another maven module, compile your main module and that specific module separately and don't have the dependencies you don't want to have in your main module; then reference that specific @Configuration root class loading your Spring context (for example, via `contextConfigLocation` context parameter).

Or you could use dirty `Class.forName()`+`newInstance()` techniques in your @Configuration.

Of course, the option you mention (a mix of @Configuration + XML-based configs) is also possible.